# Django - Foreign key reverse creation

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Imagine this model:

```
class ExercisePart(models.Model):
  exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise)
  sequence = models.IntegerField()
  class Meta:
    unique_together = (('exercise', 'sequence',),)

class Exercise(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

From the admin interface I'd like to be able to create/link `ExercisePart`s through the `Exercise` page. I'd like to do that because I wish to avoid having to go on another page each time I want to add an `ExercisePart`s.

Is it possible ? How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [inline admin feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).

admin.py

```
class ExercisePartInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = ExercisePart
class ExerciseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [ExercisePartInline]
```

Comment: That is precisely what I was thinking of ! I didn't know of this feature. Thanks